# Store different PySpark schema in one column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I try to extract different tables from REST API in PySpark. I followed this [link](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-execute-a-rest-api-call-on-apache-spark-the-right-way-in-python-4367f2740e78). I want to store the different schema in one column in a pyspark dataframe. Here is an example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *

A = [{"TableName": "Table1", "Schema": StructType([StructField("a", StringType()), StructField("b", IntegerType())])}
    , {"TableName": "Table2", "Schema": StructType([StructField("b", StringType()), StructField("c", IntegerType())])}]
df_A = spark.createDataFrame(A)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring
```

Is it possible to achieve this result?

Comment: OK, I thought I could vary the schema when I defined the udf function udf_getRestAPI_Catalite = udf(getRestAPI_Catalite, schema) but it didn't work. I wanted to use the parallel processing for extracting the data from REST API but I guess it doesn't if there are different schema's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use different data type like `StructType` or `StringType` in spark, we  are trying to define how the value in dataframe or column looks like, it's a description and definition but not a value. Therefore, you can't save it as a `value` inside the column.

If you really want to save the schema of different table, why don't you save it as a string?

```
A = [{"TableName": "Table1", "Schema": """StructType([StructField("a", StringType()), StructField("b", IntegerType())])"""}
    , {"TableName": "Table2", "Schema": """StructType([StructField("b", StringType()), StructField("c", IntegerType())])"""}]
df_A = spark.createDataFrame(A)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
|Schema                                                                       |TableName|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
|StructType([StructField("a", StringType()), StructField("b", IntegerType())])|Table1   |
|StructType([StructField("b", StringType()), StructField("c", IntegerType())])|Table2   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Then you can parse your schema when you create your own UDF.

Comment: Hello Jonathan. Thanks for your answer. However, it seems my UDF function doesn't recognize the schema as a string. How can I convert it back as a struct type?

Comment: Hi @Quynh-MaiChu, not sure if I understand your question correctly, if you want to convert your schema string back to spark object, you can check function like `eval()`. What do you want to achieve in your UDF actually?

Comment: I have an UDF function that execute a get REST API from ODATA and I want to do the extraction based on the provided link. My difficulty is that the schema changes based on the API request. I think I found the solution by converting doing ```StructType.simpleString()```. My only struugle is to know how to deal with special character like @

Comment: I validate the answer since it works for the example :)